# how does the jvm handle polymorphism and its optimization

Tags: c++, jvm, polymorphism, virtual

I have the stituation that there is an Interface I with a method m, and two implementation classes A and B that behave differently.

the objects of A and B use only memory for their value and reference types, not for their methods. An object of A stored in a variable of type I is stored with a reference (pointer size overhead) plus the size of the object. Now the method m is called. Now where is this one bit of information stored, that method m from class A has to be called instead from class B?

This question also nags me with C++ virtual methods.

```
interface I { void m(); }
class A implements I { void m(){println("a");} }
class B implements I { void m(){println("b");} }
```

Comment: [Virtual Method Tables on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Comment: Who says that "he objects of A and B use only memory for their value and reference types, not for their methods"? That's a pretty bold assertion (and probably false).

Comment: might be true that this assumption might be false, thats exactly why I am asking this question. But my visualVM analysis showed me, that only space for value types and references is used, not for methods. But I am not shure how serious I can take these tests, because I don't know the optimizations that are still made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, each object typically contains a hidden pointer (the *vptr*) to a table of function addresses (the *vtable*).  There is one vtable per class, containing the addresses of its virtual function implementations.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table.

I imagine Java implements things in a similar manner (although I haven't looked into this).

Comment: this means an object of a class with virtual functions is always one size of a pointer bigger than an object without virtual functions? Are there situations, where this overhead might be reduced to one byte?

Comment: @Arne: I guess it's possible in theory.  But I doubt any implementation does so (it would limit the total number of classes in a hierarchy to 256, for a start).

Answer (score 1):

In actual executing code (JIT) at least the Hotspot JVM can sometimes call the correct method directly (effectively de-virtualizing it) *if* it can be certain of which one it is. As it also handles the class loading the class hierarchy is known so if there are no instances of B around it can be certain it is A for example (monomorphic). If later on instances of B are created it can de-optimize back and still do some optimizations (only two alternatives still, bimorphic).

Comment: I am shure that Hotspot can do a lot of optimization, but lets assume that the jvm has no idea weather the object is from class A or B.